# Action<List<Something>> contravariance limitation

Tags: c#, list, action, contravariance

I'm writing a networked application where objects are requested by id and are returned via a delegate callback:

```
public static void requestById<ModelType>(T id, Action<ModelType> callback)
    where ModelType : AbstractModel<T>
{
}
```

For convenience I have a method for requesting multiple objects at a time:

```
public static void requestByIds<ModelType>
    (List<T> ids, Action<List<ModelType>> callback)
    where ModelType : AbstractModel<T>, new()
{
}
```

Further down the line I have an abstract model object that has multiple children, and a method for requesting it's children:

```
public abstract void requestSections(Action<List<AbstractSection>> callback);
```

And then an implementation in a concrete class:

```
public override void requestSections(Action<List<AbstractSection>> callback)
{
    Section.requestByIds<Section>(this.sectionIds, callback);
}
```

Suddenly I find the delegate

```
Action<List<AbstractSection>>
```

is incompatible with

```
Action<List<Section>>
```

Is this a limitation of contravariance in C#? Is there any kind of workaround so I can get my override method to work? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`List` is invariant, it is not covariant or contravariant.

If you use an `IEnumerable<T>` rather than a list, than you can rely on `IEnumerable<T>` being covariant with repsect to `T`, which makes `Action<IEnumerable<T>>` contravariant with respect to `T`.

Comment: I've changed my parameter types to use `Action<IEnumberable<T>>` and I'm still finding it complains about the covariance of `Action<List<AbstractSection>>` and `Action<List<Section>>`

Comment: @Vesuvian Of course you will, because you can't convert an `Action<List<AbstractSection>>` to an `Action<List<Section>>`, precicely because `List` is invariant.  You can however convert an `Action<IEnumerable<AbstractSection>>` to an `Action<IEnumerable<Section>>`.

Comment: sorry, I mistyped, I meant to write: "`Action<IEnumberable<AbstractSection>>` and `Action<IEnumberable<Section>>`".

I believe this is because I am trying to convert an abstract to a concrete rather than concrete to abstract.

Comment: @Vesuvian No, i;n this case an `Action<IEnumerable<T>>` is contravariant with respect to `T`, not covariant.  That conversion should work just fine; you apparently are not making that type of conversion if you're getting an error.